# Windows Task Manager shows process memory keeps growing even though there are no memory leaks

Tags: memory, memory-leaks

My application keeps consuming more and more memory as seen in the Windows Task Manager and eventually crashes due to OutOfMemory. However when i check for leaks using MemoryValidator (from www.softwareverify.com) no leaks are detected. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

Just because there is a growing amount of memory usage doesn't mean it is necessarily 'leaking'. You could simply be accumulating a large number of live objects and/or very large ones (containing lots and lots of data).

If you can provide more information about what language(s) you are using and what the application is doing I can perhaps help out with some more specific information!

**UPDATE AS PER COMMENTS**
Well, you'll just want to make sure the garbage collection is happening correctly. I'd suggest the libgc library to help with that perhaps.
http://developers.sun.com/solaris/articles/libgc.html

The only other thing I could think of as being the cause of this is that you are maintaining references to the objects somewhere unintentionally so they are just piling up.

Comment: Mine is a C++ transactional application. During a transaction it creates a lots of objects and deletes them when the transaction ends. So the memory is supposed to come back to original. But in the Task Manager it keeps increasing steadily.

Comment: I don't need to garbage collect in the C++ application as I'm explicitly deleting the objects no longer needed. I just found a few pages on the internet such as http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/BestPractices5.aspx?msg=3605652&display=Mobile#Avoidtaskmanagertodetectmemoryleak that say that the Task Manager shows the memory allocated and not the memory in use. I wonder if I'm mistakenly thinking that my application is leaking memory. The above link tells to use perfmon to check private memory growth of an application, but I'm not able to find my application in the "instances" list.

Comment: @Hugh The 'delete' isn't full proof as a garbage collection method, and I think (though I am not sure) that ligbc would take care of the allocation problem (if there is one). That's all I've got unfortunately.. good luck!